# Jar cannot find txt File in FileOutputStream

Tags: java, javafx, resources, text-files

**I am trying to save and get Player objects from a Textfile and it works when using my IDE but when i create a Jar it can't find the text File. I tried with

```
this.getClas().getResources(path)
```

But still it didnt find the path to my text file.Can anybody Help?

```
  public void setPlayer() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Player> playerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        playerArrayList = getPlayers();

        Player player = new Player();
        player.name = ViewManager.name;
        player.score = Collision.points;
        playerArrayList.add(player);
        try{

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("src/resources/highscore.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            for(Player player1 : playerArrayList){
                out.writeObject(player1);
            }

            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

´´´´
```

Comment: The error "can't find" refers to the **directory** `src` or `resources`, not to the file itself. The error messages from the old `File` API are notoriously misleading, so use the newer NIO.2 `Path` API instead, where the error messages are much better and more informative. Anyway, when you run from the Jar file, does the current directory have an `src` subdirectory, with a `resources` sub-subdirectory? The error would indicate the answer is: *No*.

Comment: You should not write to a file which is inside a jar file. You can do it so. I think you are trying to serialize an object, it should be outside of the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

Resource files are not physical `File`s, as they can be inside a jar. They are intended to be read-only, and the class loader may cache them. They are case sensitive, with `/` as path separator and there path starts at the class path's root, probably src/resources.

So use the resource file as fall back resource to copy, if some physical file does not exist.

```
Path appDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + ".myapp");
Files.createDirectories(appDir);

Path file = appDir.resolve("highscore.txt");
if (!Files.exists(file)) {
    // Copy resource to file, either:
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/highscore.txt");
    Path templatePath = Paths.get(url.toURI());
    Files.copy(templatePath, file);

    // Or
    InputStream templateIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/highscore.txt");
    Files.copy(templateIn, file);
}

try (FileOutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(file)) {
    ...
}
```

Path is the generalisation of File.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what IDE you're using, but you're writing the file to the source sub directory. That directory might not be included in the jar.